# problem with plotting several plots with mcmc_areas() function

Tags: r, plot, bayesian

So, I wanted to create several plots of my posterior sample using bayesplot.
My data contains several draws divided into features (the column "correlation" contains the posterior values):

`head(cors_feat[cors_feat$feature==1,])`

```
  feature correlation
1       1  -0.5002517
2       1   0.1964202
3       1  -0.8603918
4       1  -0.7111672
5       1   0.1760033
6       1   0.2788863
```

`head(cors_feat[cors_feat$feature==2,])`

```
      feature correlation
40001       2  -0.7149123
40002       2  -0.7666210
40003       2  -0.7542937
40004       2  -0.2094619
40005       2   0.4089077
40006       2  -0.8550481
```

I loop through the features, and in the loop I use the function mcmc_areas() to create the plots:

```
lst <- list()
for (i in 1:length(unique(cors_feat$feature))){
  lst <- c(lst,mcmc_areas(cors_feat[cors_feat$feature==i,], pars = c("correlation"), prob = 0.95))
}
```

When I try to use the plot_grid function from from the "cowplot" library I get the following error:

```
plot_grid(plotlist = lst)
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

And most importantly, I cannot see any plot.

How can I solve this issue?